# Is it possible to make the Case Deflection Satisfaction questions mandatory in the component?

Tags: case, servicecloud, experience-cloud

**PROBLEM:** We are using the case deflection component on our community site and we are wanting to get more engagement from the Satisfaction suggestion prompt. We are finding a very low number of users are filling this out after reading an article, which is making it near impossible to get data on whether these articles are deflecting case creation.

**QUESTION:** Is there a way (ideally without too much customisation) to make this mandatory? Or is there a better alternative to track case deflection metrics?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't make them mandatory. To improve the number of responses, reduce the number of questions, preferably to two: "Is your issue resolved?" and "Can we follow up with a survey?". Capture the answers independently, and for the survey question, if the survey isn't completed within an hour, email it.

The challenge with gathering CSAT metrics is looking at the process from the customer's POV as well as the business goals.

HTH